# Custom API Controller returns 404 from React client using VS React and ASP.NET Core template

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, vite

I created a .NET 8 project using the React and ASP.NET Core (Typescript) template which uses vite.  I can run the project and it returns the weather data from the WeatherForecast controller.  I added my own API controller with a get method that returns data which runs successfully from Swagger or Postman but when I call it from React, I get 404 not found.  I added an entry to the vite.config.ts to include my api:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [plugin()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '^/weatherforecast': {
                target: 'https://localhost:7099/',
                secure: false
            }**,
            '^/clients': {
                target: 'https://localhost:7099/',
                secure: false
            }**
        },
        port: 5173,
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(certFilePath),
        }
    }
})
```

In my App.tsx, I have a function that calls to get the clients:

```
    async function populateClientData() {
        const response = await fetch('clients');
        const data = await response.json();
        setClients(data);
    }
```

And my ClientsController.cs:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<List<Client>> Get()
        {
            var results = await _context.Clients.ToListAsync();

            return results;
        }
```

I also added an entry to the .Server.http file in the ASP.NET server project:

```
@TestProject.Server_HostAddress = http://localhost:5108

GET {{TestProject.Server_HostAddress}}/weatherforecast/
Accept: application/json

**GET {{TestProject.Server_HostAddress}}/clients/
Accept: application/json**
```

How do I configure the app so the React client app will make calls to my custom server APIs?

I tried configuring the vite.config.ts to include my custom API.  I would expect that when I call fetch within my react app, it will retrieve the data from my server API.  Instead, I am getting a 404 page not found.

Comment: i dont full understand the vite.config but when you query clients shouldnt you be doing https://localhost:7099/clients?  can you show the url of the request as its being sent in the network tab?

Comment: does your controller specify a different route?
What address are you successfully hitting in postman?

Comment: The route of the controller is "api/[controller]" which translates to "api/clients".  The url which works in Postman is "https://localhost:7099/api/clients".  I don't understand how the react client is mapping "https://localhost:5173/weatherforecast" to "https://localhost:7099/api/weatherforecast".  When looking at the browser dev tools, the react app is using "https://localhost:5173/weatherforecast" for the weather (works) and "https://localhost:5173/clients" for the clients request (doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to get it to work.  It turns out the weatherforecast contoller has a route of "[controller]" and the clients controller has a route of "api/[controller]".  If I make the clients controller route to "[controller]" then it works.  I tried different ways to get the "api/[controller]" to work but everything I tried failed.  I would prefer to use "api/[controller]" because now I need to make sure my react paths and server paths are unique.  If anyone knows how to get the "api/[controller]" to work, let me know.

Thanks.